# Consolibyte Quickbooks PHP SDK (web connector) - Authentication failed

Tags: php, web, quickbooks, connector, intuit-partner-platform

I am using Consolibyte's PHP Dev Kit for Quick Books Desktop and i get an authentication failure with the following message:
20200319.12:39:20 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

.QWC FILE:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
 <AppName>Local Netexem</AppName>
 <AppID></AppID>
 <AppURL>https://bitsclan-solutions.com/quickbooks/qbwc</AppURL>
 <AppDescription>Netexem Quickbooks</AppDescription>
 <AppSupport>https://bitsclan-solutions.com/quickbooks/qbwc</AppSupport>
 <UserName>username</UserName>
 <OwnerID>{b7177e65-2f70-a214-214c-aed509cd911e}</OwnerID>
 <FileID>{ba656061-e8a4-0a24-95fa-aa6c74b5f6b9}</FileID>
 <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
 <Notify>false</Notify>
 <Scheduler>
  <RunEveryNMinutes>1</RunEveryNMinutes>
 </Scheduler>
 <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

QWC LOG:

```html
20200322.23:31:33 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'Local Netexem' has STARTED
20200322.23:31:33 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20200322.23:31:33 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20200322.23:31:33 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20200322.23:31:33 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20200322.23:31:33 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: Local Netexem
20200322.23:31:33 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): Local Netexem
20200322.23:31:33 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://bitsclan-solutions.com/quickbooks/qbwc
20200322.23:31:33 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20200322.23:31:34 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <Client found response content type of 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20200322.23:31:34 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20200322.23:31:34 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.3.0.36">
20200322.23:31:34 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <Client found response content type of 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.
20200322.23:31:34 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20200322.23:31:34 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'Local Netexem', username = 'username'
20200322.23:31:34 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="username"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20200322.23:31:35 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Client found response content type of 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
20200322.23:31:35 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20200322.23:31:35 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20200322.23:31:35 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

This: `The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.`

Means that you either have:

1. A misconfigured web server, which is rejecting `POST` requests to your URL
2. A PHP script which is sending a `403 Forbidden` header (probably via https://www.php.net/header )

Fix your code or your web server configuration.

This is what you get if you try to `POST` to the URL:

[image]

You should find out if this is a `403 Forbidden` page that *your code* is producing (maybe you're using a framework like Laravel or CodeIgnitor or something that is generating this?) or something that *your web host* is producing.

Comment: Thank You !
403 Forbidden error solved and i shifted my project to another domain and now i am getting " QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message. Client fou......"

Comment: Have you actually visited that URL? You're `print_r`ing something that you shouldn't be. Please post your code if you need more help.